# TargetParameterCountException: the parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5, dispatcher

Below my view model and data model from my WPF MVVM app. I am having problems when performing the invoke (see below), the exception parameter count mismatch is thrown. The method "getDataFromDatabase" is returning a collection of "UserData". So how to solve this?

**View Model**:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private static Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    public ObservableCollection<UserData> lstUsers

    public ObservableCollection<UserData> LstUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lstUsers;
        }

        private set
        {
            this.lstUsers= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstUsers");
        }
    }

    // LoadData is called from the constructor of the view code-behind (xaml.cs) once DataContext is correctly set.
    public void LoadData()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
        {
            var result = getDataFromDatabase();
            UIThread((p) => LstUsers = result);
        }));
    }

    ObservableCollection<UserData> getDataFromDatabase()
    {            
        return this.RequestDataToDatabase();
    }

    static void UIThread(Action<object> a)
    {
        if(_dispatcher == null) 
        {
           _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        _dispatcher.Invoke(a); <---- HERE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
    }
}
```

**Data Model**:

```
public class UserData
{
   public string ID{ get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }

   // Other properties
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Will your method `getDataFromDatabase` getting called? And you should set the dispatcher in your constructor and not in the method `UIThread`.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Yes, method getDataFromDatabase is called and returning the collection correctly. See my updated post. ThreadPool is created on a method in view model which is called from the view (constructor) once datacontext is correctly set.

Comment: Would you mind debugging once again, this time more detailed, line-by-line debug session, so you can find the exact line of code that throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Action<object>` is an Action with a parameter of type object. It would have to be invoked via the [`Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509(v=vs.110).aspx) overload with a single parameter:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(a, someObject);
```

So change `Action<object>` to `Action`:

```
static void UIThread(Action a)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(a);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
UIThread(() => LstUsers = result);
```

---

You may also want to make your LoadData method async and write it like this:

```
public async Task LoadData()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var result = getDataFromDatabase();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => LstUsers = result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Working! Also I like very much your solution to make LoadData method async. Unfortunatelly Task is not being supported in NET 3.5 so is it possible to adapt it in some way?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary) and [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). Otherwise, ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem should be quite ok.